# JMeter - Can't click on the body data tab

Tags: jmeter

Apache JMeter 5.4.1: I can't click on the body data tab. how can I do this?
[image]

Comment: Please consider providing a [mcve], together with expectations and observations. "I can't click" isn't quite complete, as you certainly can click, but expected some different behavior than observed _after you did something_. What did you do that led you to this situation?

Comment: delete all the parameters and then try

Comment: @user7294900 i tried but I still can't click

Comment: send parameters with request should be empty

Comment: Thanks, it really worked. I'm so new to Jmeter that I'm sorry if I asked you something absurd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter doesn't allow to define both Parameters (under `Send Parameters With the Request`) and [Body Data](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request), you must delete all data before use different option

> Note that once you leave the Tree node, you cannot switch back to the parameter tab unless you clear the Body Data tab from its data

- You can add to Files Upload tab files while having either parameters or body

Answer (score 1):

The process of clicking on the "Body Data" tab is very complex, so please read below instructions very carefully, you will need to:

1. Hover your mouse cursor over the "Body Data" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler
2. Perform left mouse click (or equivalent for your operating system)

Note that if you have something in the "Parameters" tab - you won't be able to use Body Data or vice versa so you need to choose one of these options.

Demo:

[image]

If you're not too comfortable with building JMeter's HTTP Request samplers manually it might be a better idea considering recording your test scenario using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/)